# Google Service account oauth redirect uri

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

My application needs service account authorization. Everything is fine as long as I get the authorization.

My Question is: How do I know when a user gives me the authorization? There is no redirect uri as everyone notes so how do I get a callback? Is there an api that gives me the list of users that I have access to?

As of now I'm attempting to use oauthtoscombined to get the token for the simple account and the service account in the same process. But I cannot find any instructions on how. So if this is the right way, could someone point me in the right direction or explain how it works? Simply modifying the redirect uri doesnt work.

I have the marketplace app setup and it works alright with the test oauth flow but again, I cant find out how to get a callback.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Splitting the answer up a bit:

```
How do I know when a user gives me the authorization?  
There is no redirect uri as everyone notes so how do I get a callback?
```

[Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) are set up in APIs console to access your own data, not someone else's. There is no call back because there is no user interaction in a service account.

> The Google OAuth 2.0 endpoint supports server-to-server interactions
>   such as those between a web application and Google Cloud Storage. For
>   this scenario you need a service account, which is an account that
>   belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. For
>   example, if you use the Google Prediction API to act on behalf of your
>   application without accessing any user data, your application uses its
>   service-account credentials to prove its own identity, and no end user
>   is involved

Suggestion: Use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) if you would like to access information owned by someone else.

```
Is there an api that gives me the list of users that I have access to?
```

No there is not.  Once you have Oauth2 set up you will need to save the Refresh Tokens returned by the Authentication server.  A refresh token is returned for each of the users that have granted you access to there accounts. You will then be able request data again on there behalf by using the Refresh Token to get a new access token.

Comment: that doesn't make sense if you look at this page:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

It clearly states that "In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In Google Apps domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0."

Comment: To clarify, I have it working fine with the current process. Although i have only tested it on my own domain using the test install flow. Yet I am able to connect to drive and do everything.